# Error importing app from backup on wit.ai

Tags: wit.ai

Since this weekend, when I try to create a new app in Wit.ai by importing from a backup just saved from another app I get a blank error message and the new app receive only part of the information from the backup.

[Here is the blank error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlDa5.png)

Has anyone encoutered the same problem? Any suggestions on why it may be and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept receiving same error. In my case it had nothing to do with the content and/or formatting and/or encoding of any of *.json files.

Solution that works for me now is:

1) Export zip from any Wit.ai application (Even completely empty)

2) Copy all *.json files that are meant to be uploaded directly to this zip - overwrite or append files as needed

3) Import your app from a backup using this modified zip file

Comment: in no 1) you mean 'export zip from any OTHER wit.ai app', right?

Answer (score 1):

If you tamper with the original archive, do not add directory entries to the backup.

```
zip --no-dir-entries project.zip -r project

adding: project/actions.json (stored 0%)
adding: project/app.json (stored 0%)
adding: project/entities/intent.json (stored 0%)
adding: project/stories.json (stored 0%)
```

will work.

Adding the directory entry for entities

```
adding: project/entities/ (stored 0%)
```

seems to break the importer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact problems. So if anyone else stumble upon this. Check that your bot is valid and has no empty bookmarks (first issue), recursive errors (had this as well) or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I notice the same issue with the new wit.ai ui. So I just use the previous version of api for backup and restore