# Create an app in Wit.ai from zip

Tags: wit.ai

I'm trying to build a sample app in Wit.AI, with a lot of entity values and expressions. Thus, to create that app manually is not an option.

I've tried their "import" feature, but it seems it doesn't work very well or it might be very capricious about the zip. The things I've done and nothing gave a result:

1. Download a zip from another app in my account
2. Change the zip command in order to work for the new app
3. The changed files are expressions.json and a single file in the entities folder, describing an user-defined entity.
4. Zip the whole folder in order to preserve the structure of the ZIP

Nevertheless how many approaches I've tried (format the JSON and etc.) nothing worked! The server returns 400 Bad Request response.

Further, I've tried with their Web API, but to no avail again. When I'm [updating the values of an entity](https://wit.ai/docs/http/20170307#put--entities-:entity-id-link) the server responses with Success, the response doesn't contain the new values...

I've checked this article [Error importing app from backup on wit.ai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40205952/error-importing-app-from-backup-on-wit-ai) and many others as well as some issues on GitHub, but again...nothing helped ;)

So, if anyone could help on that...He/she gets a beer! :)

Comment: using the curl commands instead of creating analogical ajax calls does the trick...

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new app, you can simply upload the the zip file in *Import your app from a backup*, and create the new app.
To be sure to not include any redundant files in the app zip file, it is **important** to use the following to zip app files:

```
zip AppName.zip AppName/app.json AppName/entities/*.json AppName/expressions.json
```

and upload `AppName.zip`. 
Note that, the name of new app, zip file, and app name in `app.json` file, all should be the same (here `AppName`).

[image]